# Move button to top-right position in translucent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, position, transparent, android-button

I want to move my button at top-right position on my activity.

In my layout, the button is on top-right position, but when I start activity it appears in center vertically.

Here's my layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MainClass" >

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:text="UL" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my styles.xml code:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    </style>
    <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And finally here's my Activity code:

```
package com.test.app;

import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.app.*;

public class MainClass extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
    }
}
```

screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code only and the button is appearing on top right.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Layout is okey.
Make change in style.xml as below.

```
<resources>
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
</style>
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Yes, that code is working IF I DONT WANT TRANSPARENT SCREEN!!

Comment: I got the solution, make <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>                           as <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>

Comment: you want click event on button click?

Comment: see this link http://horribile.blogspot.in/2011/11/two-activities-on-screen-at-same-time.html   might be helpful to you.